# Javafx Link/Bind Treeview Items to ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to find an easy way of linking a **TreeView** of type Download to an **ObservableList** of the same type.

**MainController.java**

```
public class MainController {

    private ObservableList<Download> downloads = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML private TreeView<Download> $TreeDownloads;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        $TreeDownloads.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        $TreeDownloads.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        $TreeDownloads.setShowRoot(false);

        downloads.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Download>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Download> c) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    addDownloads(c.getAddedSubList());
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    //
                }
            }
        });
        downloads.add(new Download("3847"));
        downloads.add(new Download("3567"));
        downloads.add(new Download("2357"));
    }

    private void addDownloads(List<? extends Download> downloads) {
        downloads.forEach(download -> {
            TreeItem<Download> treeItem = new TreeItem<>(download);
            $TreeDownloads.getRoot().getChildren().add(treeItem);
            new Thread(download::start).start();
        });
    }

    private void removeDownloads(List<? extends Download> downloads) {
        // remove treeitems from the treeview that hold these downloads
    }
}
```

**Download.java**

```
public class Download {

    private DoubleProperty progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0D);
    private StringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Download(String id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public void start() {
        while (progress.getValue() < 1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                progress.add(0.1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }      

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id.getValue();
    }
}
```

How do i implement a **remove** by **Object(Download)** mechanism, and is there an easier way to bind observablelist's items to a treeview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not entirely certain what the exact problem is, all pretty straightforward:

First off, your list change listener implementation is incorrect, it must advance the subChanges before accessing its state (you did run your posted code, or not ;)

```
downloads.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Download>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Download> c) {
        // this while was missing
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                addDownloads(c.getAddedSubList());
            }
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                // accessing the list of removed elements is .. plain standard api 
                removeDownloads(c.getRemoved());
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Now implement the removal of the corresponding treeItems:

```
private void removeDownloads(List<? extends Download> downloads) {
    // remove treeitems from the treeview that hold these downloads
    List<TreeItem<Download>> treeItemsToRemove = treeDownloads.getRoot().getChildren().stream()
            .filter(treeItem -> downloads.contains(treeItem.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    treeDownloads.getRoot().getChildren().removeAll(treeItemsToRemove);
}
```

---

Asides:

- java naming conventions use lowercase letters for members: treeDownloads (not $TreeDownloads)
- the "verifiable" in MCVE implies being runnable as-is: the poster should be the first to verify that ;) yours wasn't due to incorrect implementation of the listener
- the "minimal" in MCVE means leaving out everything that's not needed: f.i. calling the threading code - which in your first snippet was particularly distracting because violating fx' threading rule is a rather common error

Comment: Got you, thanks for the solution and tips ;)
As for the way i named the treeview variable, it's only a convention for my code base, all fxml ui controls start with a $ControlName. I found it makes debugging easier

Comment: @DarkMental fair enough - though you might consider to not use such a private convention in public code :)

Comment: That makes sense, i'll do that from now on, thanks for the advice :)